# set custom attribute and value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class='progress-20'>
```

I want to alter the progress-20 with other value, I've get the value by custom expression.

Comment: how do you know which is the element and what is the value you want it to be changed to

Comment: whether the element could have other values in the class attribute like `<div class='someclass progress-20'>`

Comment: Why not use data-* attributes? The purpose of classes is not this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  to set the class attribute of the element. You need to select the div for that you can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

```
$('.progress-20').attr('class','newclass');
```

**Edit** based on comments.

You can use [starts with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) if 20 could change

```
$('[class^=progress-]').attr('class','newclass');
```

Comment: the problem is the attr doesn't always 20, 20 is only the default.. what if it's dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.progress-20').attr('class','new_value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) like,

```
$('div').toggleClass('progress-20 newclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja2SU/

**OR** this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/bFLju/

*API:

- `attr` http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- `removeAttr` http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
- `addClass` http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

you could use `attr` or `removeClass` and then `addClass`

Gave you few choices hope anyone will fit you need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    alert(' before altering => ' + $('div').attr('class'));
    $('div').attr('class', 'foobar');
    alert(' after altering => ' + $('div').attr('class'));
});
```

**or**

```
$(function () {
    $('div').removeAttr('class').addClass('foobar');
});
```